# How to properly get user credential from AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.AuthorizeAsync()? [Google+/Gmail API]

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to integrate Google+ and Gmail APIs into my app, so that users can log in with their Google accounts and send emails from within the application.

I tried to follow the official guides and docs, and after succesfully implementing external login I've got a bit stuck at retrieving the user's credential when trying to set up a Gmail service (frankly, I find the docs quite unclear, so I might be not seeing something really obvious).

Resources I've used:

[Configuring OAuth 2.0 for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

[Sending emails with Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

---

### The problem:

After the execution of `var authState = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(token);` ends, the authState.Credential property is **always** equal to **null**.

### FlowMetadata implementation

```
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get
        {

            return _flow;
        }
    }

    private readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow _flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer()
    {
        ClientSecrets = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "id-placeholder",
            ClientSecret = "secret-placeholder"
        },
        DataStore = new FileDataStore("Google.Apis.Auth.Data", true),
        Scopes = new string[]{
            GmailService.Scope.GmailSend,
            GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose,
            GmailService.Scope.GmailModify
        }
    });

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        return controller.User.Identity.GetUserId();   
    }
}
```

### Send Email action

```
    [HttpPost]
    private async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(CancellationToken token, MailMessage email)
    {
        var authState = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata())
            .AuthorizeAsync(token); 
        if (authState.Credential == null) // <<- it's always true, so it always gets redirected
            return Redirect(authState.RedirectUri);


        var service = new GmailService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() {
            ApplicationName = "MyApp",
            HttpClientInitializer = authState.Credential
        });

        var message = Base64UrlEncode(email);
        await service.Users.Messages.Send(message, "me").ExecuteAsync();
        return new EmptyResult();

     }
```

---

If I were to guess what's the matter I'd place my bets on the GetUserId method (since it's used when running AuthorizeAsync), although in that event I don't really know how it should be implemented.

So, going back to the original question - can anyone tell me why am I getting a null back there, and what can I do to proceed with the authorization properly?
I would be grateful for pointing out any mistakes, or simply shedding some light on the subject.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, too bad it has never been answered.